# Find the equation of plane through the x-axis and another point.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for the equation of a plane which passes through the x-axis and the point A(3,1,-4), and am confused as to how to go about solving the problem. I am thinking that I can  take two random points that cross the x-axis, and then take the cross product of two vectors created by the three points. From that I would get the vector perpendicular to the plane, and then I would be able to get the equation of the plane. Would my approach be correct, or is there a simpler way of finding the equation of the plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation for a plane which contains the $x$-axis is $y+cz=0$ for some constant $c$.  For the plane to contain the point $(3,1,-4)$ you need to have $1-4c=0$.